# Heap Space error in Druid while injecting data

Tags: ubuntu, druid

I am facing an issue while injecting one billion data by native-batch injection from Postgresql through json . I made configurations in jvm config for each services as min=2048mb,max=4096mb,and had also increased middlemanager directmemeorysize to 12gb ,in tuning config I specified maxRowsInMemory=2000000, and successfully ingested 5000000(50lak) data.

Druid and PostgreSQL is on different server.

But when I tried to inject one billion data using same specification it shows **"heap space outofmemory error"**.

**Please help me to resolve my issue. I need to ingest 1Billion data from PostgreSQL to Druid.**

Comment: Have you tuned your [MiddleManager](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/basic-cluster-tuning.html#middlemanager)?